# Issue with importing class

Tags: python, class, import

I have Main.py

```
class Juden:
       def __init__(self, username, password):
           self.login()
           self.Search()
           self.NewPosts
           <some code>
       def login(self):
           <some code>
       def Search(self):
           <some code>
       def NewPosts(self):
           <some code>
       def ComLikFol(self):
           <some code>
```

I would like to use some of the definitions in my second file. When I type **import Main** and click run, program executes every definition that is initiated. How can I use specific definitions? I mean at the beggining I would like to use login, then do a search loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to choose username and password, then write it in brackets

```
import main as mn
username = 'ignesuss'
password = 'qwerty'
obj = mn.Juden()
obj.login(username, password)
```

Answer (score 0):

note that call your class 'Main' is not suitable

```
from Juden import login
```

and if you wanna import more:

```
from Juden import login, Search
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'login' from 'Main'

Comment: you did not specify the calss name, so now: from Juden import login, Search

Answer (score 0):

> Solution 1:

Your main file **init** should contains only the following:

```
class Juden:
       def __init__(self, username, password):
           <Some code>
       def login(self):
           <some code>
       def Search(self):
           <some code>
       def NewPosts(self):
           <some code>
       def ComLikFol(self):
           <some code>
```

To call the functions use the following:

```
import main as mn
obj = mn.Juden()
obj.login
```

OR

```
from main import *
obj = Juden()
obj .login()
```

**Note: Don't write any function calls in `__init__`**

> Solution 2

Your main file **init** should contains only the following:

```
class Juden:
       def __init__(self, username, password):
           self.login()
           self.Search()
           self.NewPosts()
           <Some code>
       def login(self):
           <some code>
       def Search(self):
           <some code>
       def NewPosts(self):
           <some code>
       def ComLikFol(self):
           <some code>
```

To call the functions use the following:

```
import main as mn
obj = mn.Juden
obj.login
```

OR

```
from main import *
obj = Juden
obj .login()
```

**Note: Don't use `obj = Juden()`. If you use this it will automatically executed `__init__` function and if you want to run the `__init__` function then check Solution 1**

> Solution 3:

Your main file **init** should contains only the following:

```
class Juden:
       def __init__(self, username, password):
           self.login()
           self.Search()
           self.NewPosts()
           <Some code>
       def login(self):
           <some code>
       def Search(self):
           <some code>
       def NewPosts(self):
           <some code>
       def ComLikFol(self):
           <some code>
```

To call the functions use the following:

```
import main as mn
mn.Juden.login()
```

OR

```
from main import *
Juden.login()
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'login' from 'Main'

Comment: You main py file contains class?

Comment: Is yes then whats the class name?

Comment: Please edit the question and mention as class. I am updating the answer. Please check it

Comment: @Ignesuss  Check the edited solution and let me know if its working.

Comment: Tried solution 1, code is running, but nothing happens